# Determining if Windows 8 can install device drivers

Tags: c#, windows, device-driver

I need to install unsigned device drivers on Windows 8 machines (getting the drivers signed is not an option at this point in time). I can make this happen by having the user put the machine in a state where it will allow the installation of unsigned drivers. That process is at this web site. 
[How to disable driver signature verification on 64 bit windows 8.1 so that you can install unsigned drivers](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/).  After the system is then rebooted, my install process works.

How can it tell in my C# program if the system is in that state where it will be allowed to install unsigned device drivers?

How can I force the system into that state?

Comment: *How can I force the system into that state?* Imagine you could. Then any publisher could trick a user into installing arbitrary malware *cough* unsigned drivers, which would make driver signing worthless in the first place.

Comment: Why is it *not an option?*

Comment: See my answer for info, it should work (although I have no such driver to test with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try, and if it fails you know why. However it might be worth trying this way:

1. Ensure your program is running in admin mode (you need this for drivers anyway)
2. Run `bcdedit` and capture the STDOUT
3. Parse the output for `nointegritychecks Yes` and `testsigning Yes` (additional whitespace omitted).

More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-i-turn-off-digital-signature/a7047647-bf29-468f-a885-8e23d60f3daa).

Comment: That is not pretty, but it sounds like it would work.